# Why does the centrifugal force act normal to the surface?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia, centrifugal-force

This questions comes from understanding the Tennis Raquet's Theorem, also known as Dzhanibekov's effect in this video: [Veritasium's video](https://youtu.be/1VPfZ_XzisU)

On the second **8:36**, we can see that when they try to add some intuition to the effect, they say that it appears a centrifugal force on the small masses that acts normal to the surface:
[image: Picture of the centrifugal forces]

My question is... How are the centrifugal forces now perpendicular to the surface? Aren't the centrifugal forces pointing outside of the sphere?

Comment: The forces shown *aren't* perpendicular to the surface, they are perpendicular to the blue axis (the y-axis). Remember, the disk is spinning around the y-axis, but you don't see it in the video because the camera is spinning in lockstep with it. However, because the disk is now slightly tilted, each of the two small masses will make a small circle around the y-axis as the disk rotates. The two forces point away from that small circle.

Comment: Recommended resources for the Dzhanibekov effect:    

- 2020 Youtube video by David Brown [The Dzhanibekov effect, equations and simulations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1h4zlDRjV0c)

- 2018 Article by Nicholas Mecholsky [Analytic formula for the geometric phase of an Asymmetric top](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03867v2)

Comment: Ulshy - I just noticed you accepted the answer by Schrodinger's Cat. But, that answer doesn't even address your question ("How are the centrifugal forces now [apparently] perpendicular to the surface?"). It only explains the two kinds of reference frames, but does not actually answer what you asked in any way. I'm just curious, based on what's presented there, what did you even conclude the answer to your question is? Also, why was the correct answer by Farcher not satisfactory - any suggestions on how it can be improved or expanded to make it better?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović to be fair I saw your comment and understood everything, Schrodinger's cat answer just added a little bit more detail to the reference frames so I accepted it as there were no other post and I wanted to give him some credit. Now I see Farcher's answer which is more into what I was asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image].

The small masses rotate about the $Y$ axis in a vertical plane so the centrifugal force is at right angles, to the axis of rotation $Y$, not the surface of the disc.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, I'll need to explain the concept of inertial and non-intertial frames of reference first.
Let's say you're driving in a car on a road with a friend and there's a man crossing the road nearby.

Since you and your friend are both in the car, together you both move with the same acceleration, in the same direction.
For each other, you both are motionless. ------ (I)

However, for a man crossing the road, you both are in a moving car. Surely, from his perspective, you both are in a state of motion, accelerating forward. ------ (II)

In the example I gave above, Case (I) is what we call as a *"non-inertial frame"* while Case (II) is what we call an *"inertial frame"*.

The same applies here. In the illustration given below, in Figure (A), for a man  riding a merry-go-round, at every instant he would feel he is being thrown away from the centre by centrifugal force. He feels the force is outward because he is part of the UCM (Uniform Circular Motion), i.e., a non-inertial frame of reference. In Figure (B), we view his path from an inertial frame of reference, and now by Newton's First Law of Motion, we know that his feeling of being *"thrown outwards"* is not by an outward force, but by a force acting in **tangential to his original path**, or as you said - perpendicular to the surface.

In summation, when you look at centrifugal force form a **non-inertial frame** (that is, part of the UCM), you feel the force is outward. However, when you look at the same motion from an **inertial frame**, you realise the force is tangential to the radius of the circular motion, appearing perpendicular to the radius of motion.

Centrifugal force isn't a real force in an inertial frame; it is merely inertia in this perspective, and hence is commonly termed a 'pseudoforce' which only manifests as an *"apparent force"* for a person who is moving with the UCM.

[image]

Comment: "but by a force acting in tangential to his original path, or as you said - perpendicular to the surface" - So, where is this tangential force shown on your images? Which surface is it perpendicular to? Is it the same thing the asker is talking about?